# Excel VBA query table properties

Tags: excel, vba

I have an odbc query table which is currently working, but I need to define the field selected form the database by a value in cell D18.

The following code should replace the command text in the query table properties but it doesn't work.
debug says "Subscript out of range". if i debug and run ?text in the immediate window then run this resulting text line in SQL it returns the correct value, so the sql statement is right. what have i got wrong in the vba syntax

```
Sub Accrual()

    Text = "SELECT "
    Text = Text & "BALANCE.CDTLED_" & Range("D11").Value - 1 & " "
    Text = Text & "FROM x3sov.SOVEX.BALANCE BALANCE "
    Text = Text & "WHERE (BALANCE.ACC_0='2109') AND (BALANCE.FCY_0='S01')"

    Sheets("Control").QueryTables(1).CommandText = Text


End Sub
```

any help much appreciated

Comment: Did you convert your `QueryTable` range to a `ListObject` aka Excel table?

Comment: no. i used Data->from other sources->MS query and returned the data as a table. then i removed headers so the value is just presented in a single cell. but its still a table which i can right-click and hit refresh

Comment: So then you probably need to edit the `CommandText` of the `Connection` object instead.

Comment: querytables(0) returns error 1004 while querytables(1) returns subscript out of range

Comment: If `QueryTables(1)` returns subscript out of range you have no `QueryTables`.  Try to get the count of `ListObjects`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Excel introduced ListObjects (called Tables in the UI), you can no longer rely on `QueryTables.Count` to get to all the external data connections. If you don't have any QueryTables, then the external data connection goes through a ListObject.

```
Sheet1.ListObjects(1).QueryTable.CommandText = Text
```

Note that ListObject doesn't have a QueryTable**s** property, but a QueryTable property because there's always only one.